# Content Dialog in Windows 10 UAP

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, messagedialog

How do I made that after clicking on `PrimaryButtonClick` my ContentDialog don't close?

```
private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialogbuttonclickeventargs.cancel.aspx) property to `true`:

```
args.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: i don't have this Property

Comment: My bad check answer now